# Изменение поля одного класса из метода другого

Tags: python, ооп, инспекция-кода

Вот, помалу радую себя питоном. Бэкграунда 0, если что.

Хочу понять, правильно ли я сделал. Есть два класса: веревка и нож. Есть один обьект каждого класса. Веревка имеет длину, нож умеет отрезать веревку. 
Правильно ли я понял суть использования метода одного класса, изменяющего атрибут другого? или это кривой детский код? благодарствую за советы, аноны

```
class Rope:
    length = 30
    def get_info(self):
        print("\n", "---"*8, "\n", "class Rope, get_info(): ", "\n",
        "Rope's length is %s meters" % self.length,
        "\n", "---"*8, "\n"
    )

class Knife:
    def cut_rope(self, length, a):
        print("Now we will cut %s meters off" % length)
        a.length -= length


rope = Rope()
knife = Knife()

rope.get_info()
knife.cut_rope(12, rope)
rope.get_info()


C:\Users\олег\Python34\classes>ex2.py

 ------------------------
 class Rope, get_info():
 Rope's length is 30 meters
------------------------

Now we will cut 12 meters off

------------------------
class Rope, get_info():
Rope's length is 18 meters
```

Comment: Лучше наверное у веревки сделать метод cut

Comment: разве в реальном мире веревка может отрезать сама себя? у нее есть методы, скажем, завязаться в узел (с помощью опять же обьекта "рука" или "человек"). а у ножа может быть метод "отрезать"

Comment: Я за то, чтобы сделать верёвку иммутабельной - как строку. Разрезанная верёвка - это две новых верёвки.

Comment: А то потом в одном потоке верёвку отрежут, в другом нарастят...

Comment: Что касается `rope.get_info()` - методов интроспекции у верёвки тоже не должно быть )

Comment: _Что касается rope.get_info() - методов интроспекции у верёвки тоже не должно быть )_ почему?

Comment: Потому что верёвка не может сама на себя смотреть )

Comment: Ну хотя бы интерфейс для резки должен быть у веревки, иначе ножу придется знать как резать тот или иной объект.

Answer (score 7):

Как уже писал в комментарии, предлагаю делать верёвку иммутабельным объектом. А ещё максимально использовать встроенные методы.

```
# coding=utf-8

class Rope:
    # зачем хардкодить длину верёвки? Лучше будем задавать её в конструкторе.
    def __init__(self, length):
        if length <= 0:
            raise ValueError('length should be > 0')
        self._length = length

    # сработает с методом len()
    def __len__(self):
        return self._length

    # а это сработает с str(), соответственно и с print
    def __str__(self):
        return "This rope's length is {0!s} meters".format(self._length)


class Knife:

    # Полиморфизм! Ножу всё равно, что резать. На выходе должно быть два того же.
    # Если нарезаемое нельзя инициировать только по длине, задаваемой числом, будет ошибка.
    def cut(self, object, length):
        _class = object.__class__

        # по-хорошему, тут ещё должны быть проверки, что length не None и что число
        # и, конечно, что object не None
        if len(object) < length:
            raise ValueError('cut length exceeds available length')
        elif len(object) == length:
            # даже для одного объекта мы возвращаем список, чтобы всегда был перечислимый (iterable) результат
            return [_class(len(object))]
        else:
            return [_class(len(object) - length), _class(length)]


rope = Rope(30)
knife = Knife()

print rope

for r in knife.cut(rope, 20):
    print r
```

Вывод:

```
This rope's length is 30 meters
This rope's length is 10 meters
This rope's length is 20 meters
```

Comment: @VladimirGamalian ага, забыл форматнуть. Вот теперь вроде как true полиморфизм. ))

Comment: спасибо господа

Comment: Так и хочется вытащить метод `cut` из класса, и оставить просто "свободной" функцией. Хотя, конечно, пример изначально был игрушечный, и без класса ножа по условию не обойтись)

Comment: можно, для веревки типа str[:slice]

Comment: Все хорошо, только одно мне не очень понравилось.
Возвращаются два НОВЫХ объекта порезанных. А заявка была - отрезать кусок от имеющегося объекта.
Поэтому, в методе 'cut' я бы все же сначала изменил длину у имеющегося объекта, а потом в списке вернул уже его и новый объект с остатком.
И когда ничего не отрезаем - лучше вернуть сам объект не измененный... 
КМК.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

class Rope(str):
    def __init__(self, s: str):
        self.len = len(self)
        print("%s rope's length is %s meters" % (self, self.len))

    def __getitem__(self, item: slice):
        return self.__class__(super().__getitem__(item))


class Knife:
    @staticmethod
    def cut(string: str, length: int):
        rope = Rope(string)
        yield from (rope, rope[:length], rope[length:])
        print('{s} cut {}[{}] pos'.format(rope.len, length, s=rope))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rope = '-qwertyuiop-'
    print([(r, r.len) for r in Knife.cut(rope, 5)])
```

out:

```
-qwertyuiop- rope's length is 12 meters
-qwer rope's length is 5 meters
tyuiop- rope's length is 7 meters
-qwertyuiop- cut 12[5] pos
[('-qwertyuiop-', 12), ('-qwer', 5), ('tyuiop-', 7)]
```

Comment: Немного странно, что веревка каким-то образом привязывается к ножу. Более того, все веревки, которые резались ножом, привязываются к нему Оо

Comment: изменил, без привязки)

Comment: еще вопрос, есть класс лес и лесник. метод "посадить дерево" это метод леса или лесника)))

Comment: и какой же тут метод по вашему сажает дерево

Comment: к тому же лес растет как раз без лесника ))))